# What are better versions of "I had a lot of fun reading questions' choices."?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I wanted to say that the questions' choices were fun to read, but I feel like "questions' choices" are too unnatural. Could you give a few alternatives to that phrase, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The choices offered for this question were fun to read.

Perhaps better in the active voice:

> I had fun reading the choices offered for this question.